# seq2seq vector to letters model

Tags: neural-networks, machine-learning, deep-learning, recurrent-neural-networks, long-short-term-memory

I'm looking to build a sequence-to-sequence model that takes in a 2048-long vector of 1s and 0s as my input and translating it to my known output of (a variable length) 1-20 long characters (ex. GBNMIRN, ILCEQZG, or FPSRABBRF).

My goal is to create a model that can take in a new 2048-long vector of 1s and 0s and predict what the output sequence will look like.

I've looked at some github repositories like: https://github.com/llSourcell/seq2seq_model_live/blob/master/2-seq2seq-advanced.ipynb https://github.com/hans/ipython-notebooks/blob/master/tf/TF%20tutorial.ipynb

but I'm not sure how to implement it with my problem. Are there any projects that have done something similar to this/how could I implement this with the seq2seq models currently out there?